# How to load Xmir on Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: mir

I want to try Xmir on Ubuntu 13.10 but the results of command

```
cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log | grep -i mir
```

showing a warning

```
(WW) "xmir" is not to be loaded by default. Skipping.
```

Terminal output - sample image:
[image]

What I have to do in order to test Xmir in Ubuntu 13.10 ?

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same question. See at [ubuntu-discourse site](http://ubuntu-discourse.org/t/ubuntu-13-10-unity-final-beta-xmir-not-by-default/1067).

I've found the answer [here](http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2013/10/01/xmir-update-for-ubuntu-13-10/?utm_source=rss&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=xmir-update-for-ubuntu-13-10).

Quoting

> As many of you will know, the Mir team had two core goals for the Ubuntu 13.10 cycle:
>
> - Deliver Mir + XMir + Unity 7 on the desktop for those cards that supported it, and >fall back to X for those that don’t.
> - Deliver a native Mir + Unity 8 running on Ubuntu Touch images and devices.
>
> Unfortunately, due to some outstanding technical difficulties, we can only achieve the latter of these two goals.
>
> While we are on track to successfully deliver Mir for Ubuntu on smartphones, **we are unfortunately not going to be able to deliver Mir + XMir + Unity 7 as the default experience on the desktop.**

In order to test Xmir on 13.10 you have to install a package named: `unity-system-compositor`

Open a terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> and apply the following command (to install the package)

```
sudo apt-get install unity-system-compositor
```

After that, reboot your system for the changes to take effect.

Comment: i have done that before posting the question but the latter showed me that its skipping mir by default so only posted the question here NikTh

Comment: After the installation of `unity-system-compositor` here are my results of `cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log | grep -i mir` : http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=a95ikvbQ